# Lavalink server No mapping for GET using aws ec2 cloud

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, server, jar, pycord

first of all there is a weird problem where the server logs that it doesn't detect any profile and sets to 'default' although there is a application.yml file beside the lavalink jar
secondly I'm using pycord to connect to the server and it gives back this 'No mapping for GET' in the server log

```
2023-12-12T12:50:02.572Z  INFO 280465 --- [           main] lavalink.server.Launcher                 : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-12-12T12:50:03.863Z  WARN 280465 --- [           main] io.undertow.websockets.jsr               : UT026010: Buffer pool was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default pool will be used
2023-12-12T12:50:03.897Z  INFO 280465 --- [           main] io.undertow.servlet                      : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-12-12T12:50:03.899Z  INFO 280465 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1318 ms
2023-12-12T12:50:04.102Z  INFO 280465 --- [           main] c.s.d.l.tools.GarbageCollectionMonitor   : GC monitoring enabled, reporting results every 2 minutes.
2023-12-12T12:50:05.371Z  INFO 280465 --- [           main] l.server.config.KoeConfiguration         : OS: LINUX, Arch: X86_64
2023-12-12T12:50:05.372Z  INFO 280465 --- [           main] l.server.config.KoeConfiguration         : Enabling JDA-NAS
2023-12-12T12:50:05.377Z  INFO 280465 --- [           main] c.s.l.c.natives.NativeLibraryLoader      : Native library udpqueue: loading with filter null
2023-12-12T12:50:05.383Z  INFO 280465 --- [           main] c.s.l.c.natives.NativeLibraryLoader      : Native library udpqueue: successfully loaded.
2023-12-12T12:50:05.450Z  WARN 280465 --- [           main] l.server.config.SentryConfiguration      : Turning off sentry
2023-12-12T12:50:06.038Z  INFO 280465 --- [           main] io.undertow                              : starting server: Undertow - 2.3.6.Final
2023-12-12T12:50:06.050Z  INFO 280465 --- [           main] org.xnio                                 : XNIO version 3.8.8.Final
2023-12-12T12:50:06.061Z  INFO 280465 --- [           main] org.xnio.nio                             : XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.8.8.Final
2023-12-12T12:50:06.254Z  INFO 280465 --- [           main] org.jboss.threads                        : JBoss Threads version 3.5.0.Final
2023-12-12T12:50:06.339Z  INFO 280465 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.e.undertow.UndertowWebServer     : Undertow started on port(s) 2333 (http)
2023-12-12T12:50:06.346Z  INFO 280465 --- [           main] lavalink.server.Launcher                 : Started Launcher in 3.915 seconds (process running for 8.424)
2023-12-12T12:50:06.348Z  INFO 280465 --- [           main] lavalink.server.Launcher                 : Lavalink is ready to accept connections.
2023-12-12T12:55:24.092Z  INFO 280465 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] io.undertow.servlet                      : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-12-12T12:55:24.093Z  INFO 280465 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-12-12T12:55:24.095Z  INFO 280465 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2023-12-12T12:55:24.116Z  WARN 280465 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /
2023-12-12T12:55:24.119Z  INFO 280465 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] l.server.io.RequestLoggingFilter         : GET /
2023-12-12T12:55:27.244Z  WARN 280465 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /loadtracks
2023-12-12T12:55:27.244Z  INFO 280465 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] l.server.io.RequestLoggingFilter         : GET /loadtracks?identifier=ytsearch:hello
```

I tried making an inbound rule for port 2333 to make sure the connection isn't blocked by cloud security.. nothing really changed.